# amcharts serial Column With Rotated Series color array not working

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I have some issues with serial chart (Column With Rotated Series).
My `dataProvider` does not have a color field. I used the colors option with an array of colors, but it still does not work.
Please help me.

http://jsfiddle.net/bfbgz0sc/1/

---

zeroin thank for your response ,
amCharts Help & Support said to me  , each color within the array is reserved for every individual graph.
Unfortunately rather than defining all colors within the dataprovider is no other ways to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colors property works only for separate graphs, not for data items. So you should add colors to dataProvider.

Answer (score 2):

**Code Snippet:**

```
        //input data
    var input=[{
            "country": "USA",
                "visits": 3025
        }, {
            "country": "China",
                "visits": 1882
        }, {
            "country": "Japan",
                "visits": 1809
        }, {
            "country": "Germany",
                "visits": 1322
        }, {
            "country": "UK",
                "visits": 1122
        }, {
            "country": "France",
                "visits": 1114
        }, {
            "country": "India",
                "visits": 984
        }, {
            "country": "Spain",
                "visits": 711
        }, {
            "country": "Netherlands",
                "visits": 665
        }, {
            "country": "Russia",
                "visits": 580
        }, {
            "country": "South Korea",
                "visits": 443
        }, {
            "country": "Canada",
                "visits": 441
        }];

    //your custom colors
    var colors=    ['#FF6600', '#FCD202', '#B0DE09', '#0D8ECF', '#2A0CD0', '#CD0D74', '#CC0000', '#00CC00', '#0000CC', '#DDDDDD', '#999999', '#333333', '#990000']

    //inject color attribute with value
    for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {input[i].color = colors[i];}    

   //amCharts initialization code goes here
    ...
    ...
```

**Output**

[image]

Checkout this JSFiddle to see the solution in action:
http://jsfiddle.net/bfbgz0sc/4/